# How to create a new composable function in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, composable

Each time, I need to create a composable function, I do:

> Right click on a package -> New -> Kotlin Class/File

And I end up with this:

```
class MyClass {}
```

Now I have to do three changes manually:

1. Add `@Composable` annotation
2. Change `class` with `fun`
3. Create the `constructor`

And this is really annoying. But this is the result:

```
@Composable
fun MyClass(
    //Add arguments
) {
    //Add logic
}
```

How can I do this operation quicker? Is there any shortcut in Android Studio? I couldn't find anything in the menu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define you own template for this:

- Open the *Settings*
- Go to *Editor* > *File and Code Templates*
- Click the `+` icon to add a new template
- set the *Name* to `My Composable template` or whatever you like
- set the *Extension* to `kt`
- Copy and paste the code block from your question into the large empty text box on the right (directly under *File name*)
- Click *OK*

Then, instead of *New* > *Kotlin Class* you can click *New* > *My Composable template* (or whatever you named it), and you start without the extra manual steps.